# Spring Shedlock timing issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, shedlock

We are using Spring Shedlock library to run one instance of task at a time in clustered enviroment.
But looks like lock is held until specific time (**configured by lockAtMostFor attribute If we dont configure it takes default value from spring config**) not until task is finished.

Lets say if I configured lockAtMostFor=15 mins
no parellel task runs on any of node for 15 mins, but after 15 mins if any of node gets chance to run(or manually trigger) task its able to start it even if previous task is not finished its processing.

1.Is Shedlock is time based ?

2.Documentation(https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock) says lock is only released only when task is finished and lockAtMostFor attribute is only used in case node terminition event , but its not working
like that even if task is not finished other nodes are able to run task , other nodes are blocked from running task only if time is not elapsed (lockAtMostFor attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the documentation:

> You have to set `lockAtMostFor` to a value that is much longer than
> normal execution time. If the task takes longer than `lockAtMostFor` the
> resulting behavior may be unpredictable (more than one process will
> effectively hold the lock).

Comment: Got it , but at least lock should be released once process gets finished before lockAtMostFor time.But this is not happening , other process cant run until lockAtMostFor  time is elapsed.

Comment: @Lukas, What is the way to reset the schedlock for integration test? I tried 0 as per your post   https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock/issues/174 bot getting  lockAtMostUntil is in the past for lock on running a test

Answer (score 4):

You can find in the [documentation](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#extending-the-lock) of Shedlock that in order to extend the maximum locked time, `lockAtMostUntil`, you have to create both `SimpleLock` and `extend()` method manually. Remember that, you also have to invoke the `extend()` method manually, or by implementing a `check()` method that checks if your process is finished and invokes the `extend()` method if needed, otherwise, the lock will be automatically unlocked when it reaches the `lockAtMostUntil` time, no matter if your process is still running.

Here I am explaining how you can create the `SimpleLock` manually from `LockProvider`.
For questions about how to set the database, I recommend you read this part of the [documentation](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock#configure-lockprovider) of Shedlock.

I have used `spring boot` for my application, so the annotations that you see come from `spring boot`.

**Dependencies:**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>shedlock-spring</artifactId>
        <version>4.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.javacrumbs.shedlock</groupId>
        <artifactId>shedlock-provider-jdbc-template</artifactId>
        <version>4.23.0</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.15.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**Configuration** of `LockProvider`:

```
@EnableAsync
@Profile("!unit_test")
@Configuration
public class LockConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public LockProvider lockProvider(DataSource dataSource) {

        return new JdbcTemplateLockProvider(
                JdbcTemplateLockProvider.Configuration.builder()
                        .withTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Rome"))
                        .withJdbcTemplate(new JdbcTemplate(dataSource))
                        .withTableName("shared_lock")
                        .usingDbTime()
                        .build());
    }
}
```

**DistributedLock** here is where we implement `SimpleLock` and all the needed related methods:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class DistributedLockWithExtend {

    @Autowired
    private LockProvider lockProvider;

    private final Map<String, SimpleLock> locks = new HashMap<>();



    public boolean tryLock(String lockname, Duration lockDuration){
        Duration minDuration = Duration.ZERO;
        Instant now = ClockProvider.now();
        LockConfiguration config = new LockConfiguration(now, lockname, lockDuration, minDuration);
        Optional<SimpleLock> lockLocal = lockProvider.lock(config);
        if(lockLocal.isPresent()) {
            locks.put(lockname, lockLocal.get());
            log.debug("lock is created!");
            return true;
        }else {
            log.debug("lock is locked!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean extendLock(String lockname, Duration duration){
        Duration minDuration = Duration.ZERO;
        SimpleLock lock = locks.get(lockname);
        if(lock != null) {
            Optional<SimpleLock> localLock = lock.extend(duration, duration);
            locks.put(lockname, localLock.get());
            log.debug("Lock is extended");
            return true;
        }else {
            log.debug("There is no lock or the lock is already unlocked! Create a lock with tryLock() if you need!");
            return false;
        }

    }

    public String unLock(String lockname){

        SimpleLock lock = locks.get(lockname);
        if(lock != null) {
            locks.remove(lockname);
            lock.unlock();
            log.debug("Lock is unLocked!");
            return "Lock is unLocked!";
        }else {
            log.debug("There is no lock or the lock is already unlocked! Create a lock if you need!");
            return "There is no lock or the lock is already unlocked! Create a lock if you need!";
        }



    }
}
```

And here is a test **RestController** that I created to demonstrate the usage of the `DistributedLockWithExtend` methods:

```
@Profile("!unit_test")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(TestLockController.PATH)
public class TestLockController {

    public static final  String PATH = BaseController.PATH + "/test-lock";

    @Autowired
    ApplyPolicyScheduler applyPolicySchedular;

    @Autowired
    DistributedLockWithExtend distributedLockWithExtend;

    @GetMapping("/up")
    public String testService(){
        return "Service is up!";
    }

    @GetMapping("/invoke")
    public String invokeTest(){

        return distributedLockWithExtend.tryLock("testLockUtil", Duration.ofMinutes(1)) + "";
    }

    @GetMapping("/extend")
    public String extendTest(){

        return distributedLockWithExtend.extendLock("testLockUtil", Duration.ofMinutes(3)) + "";
    }

    @GetMapping("/unlock")
    public String unlockTest(){

         distributedLockWithExtend.unLock("testLockUtil");
         return "Unlock called!";
    }
}
```

Comment: You used: usingDbTime and TimeZone.
I get this error when used both settings:
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set both useDbTime and timeZone